# Magento2 - Setup Compile Error - Class Not_Existing_Class does not exist

Tags: magento2

I installed magento 2 Community version successfully. Now when i try to upgrade the setup i get the error **Please re-run Magento compile command**.

So i ran the compile command

```
magento setup:di:compile
```

but i am getting this error

```
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 35 min
s 736.2 MiB

  [ReflectionException]
  Class Not_Existing_Class does not exist


  [ReflectionException]
  Class Not_Existing_Class does not exist
```

Any ideas as to how this can be resolved ?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version have you installed and what version are you going to upgrade to?

Comment: @EugeneTulika - i have installed stable release from here - https://www.magentocommerce.com/download/ - version 2.0.0 of Magento Community Edition that contains Sample Data. after installation i tried running upgrade command and its giving me this error.

Comment: just tried to run it myself and didn't hit the error. The only place I see mentioned class is used is in the uint tests. Can you please post the upgrade command you run after you downloaded and installed Magento?

Comment: @EugeneTulika  - I am using WAMP server could that be causing the issue ? On my Ubuntu based machine it works fine. For upgrade i am using this command - `magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: Actually you don't need to run Magento setup:upgrade after installation, unless you installed/updated a module. However even if you run it it does not affect your installation. So still I don't have answer why do you see the error with the missing class.

Comment: ok thnx anyway for ur inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary fix, i was able to resolve this problem by commenting following line:

```
 \Not_Existing_Class $notExistingClass
```

in **<< Magento2 Root Folder >>\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Test\Unit\Generator\TestAsset\TestGenerationClass.php**

I have also reported the issue on GitHub here and awaiting the community's response: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2404

Answer (score 3):

Update setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $fileItem->getRealPath())) {
```

to

```
if (preg_match($pattern, str_replace('\\', '/', $fileItem->getRealPath()))) {
```

Check this [**Link**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e07ce7367563d1ffbb693824621e43c9f0f92cb0). Issue is fixed by Magento

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the compile process error free you have to fix the both:

**Step: 1**

In File: `[magento root dir]/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Generator/TestAsset/TestGenerationClass.php`

Just comment out this (\Not_Existing_Class $notExistingClass) line.

**Step 2:** 
In File: `[magento rootdir]/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php`

Just replace

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $fileItem->getRealPath())) {
```

WIth

```
if (preg_match($pattern, str_replace('\\', '/', $fileItem->getRealPath()))) {
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

**This was the issue:**
[image]

**Ans:**
While upgrade any module if you are facing such issue then please **setup_module** table entry. it may be null that reason we are getting such exception.
I have solved same with help of **setup_module table**.

```
UPDATE `setup_module` SET `data_version` = 'Null' WHERE `setup_module`.`module` = 'Amasty_Rules';
```

[image]