# Which is the correct code?

Tags: magento2.2.4

I am trying to fix the [ReflectionException]Class Not_Existing_Class error shown here- [Magento2 - Setup Compile Error - Class Not_Existing_Class does not exist](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90505/magento2-setup-compile-error-class-not-existing-class-does-not-exist)

The answer suggests this code change- https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e07ce7367563d1ffbb693824621e43c9f0f92cb0

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $fileItem->getRealPath()))
```

to

```
if (preg_match($pattern, str_replace('\\', '/', $fileItem->getRealPath())))
```

in the classesscanner.php file.

But when I look at my file the code is-

```
if (preg_match($pattern, str_replace('\\', '/', $fileItemPath)))
```

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the magento 2.2.4 then below code is correct.

```
if (preg_match($pattern, str_replace('\\', '/', $fileItemPath)))
```

When they are using this function in that file

```
private function isExclude($fileItemPath, $patterns)
{
    if (!is_array($patterns)) {
        $patterns = (array)$patterns;
    }
    foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
        if (preg_match($pattern, str_replace('\\', '/', $fileItemPath))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

then they are passing that $fileItemPath

```
$fileItemPath = $fileItem->getRealPath();
```

so don't get confused , your code is correct one.

Comment: That is what I thought. Do you have any ideas on how to solve https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90505/magento2-setup-compile-error-class-not-existing-class-does-not-exist if that is no longer the solution?